# Cannot open database 'filename'. It may not be a database....Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, temporary-files

Our program has an option for users to export data into an access database.  The user then downloads the database and uses this for reporting, so on and so forth.

Recently, we upgraded to Office 2007, and in testing, when downloading this database, we get the error message:

> "Cannot open database "filename" It may not be a database that your application recognizes, or the file may be corrupt."

This error only occurs when opening directly from the website, and therefore opening the database from the Temporary Files folder.  Clicking the OK button on the error message simply loads the database and everything is fine.

By saving the database to the local drive, users are able to open the database with no message boxes.

Is there a known problem with attempting to open an access database from the users Temporary Files Directory?

Answer (score 0):

The first guess is that you aren't specifying a content-length header on your Http Response. I've run into problems where this messages up the "Open" option from download dialogs before. I'd give that a check

Comment: I am running into this same problem, and my content-length is set and set correctly. I will update this thread with anything I find out.